# cant install libqt4-sql-psql on ubuntu precise unmet dependencies

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, dependencies

could someone help me resolve this ? 
I tried most of the commands here .. but none of them worked [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

```
apt-get install 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-sql-psql : Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1~precise1~ppa5 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1~precise1~ppa5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using or have been using the kubuntu backports ppa.

Check if you have pinned packages in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` preventing the install of certain package versions.

Then make sure the kubuntu backports ppa is added and updated by running the commands below. Run `apt-get install python-software-properties` (on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise) if you don't have the apt-add-repository command.

```
apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
apt-get update
```

Then try to install the package again:

```
apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql
```

If apt is completely stuck and won't let you do the above, you might need to either uninstall the broken package or force install.

```
apt-get remove libqt4-sql-psql
```

or

```
apt-get install -f
```